# Display the duplicate entries of datatable in specific format to datagridview in vb. net

Tags: vb.net, linq, datagridview, format, row

I have data table with Columns: ID, ChapterNumber, QueryID, QueryDate and Status. I have duplicate questions with same QueryID but different query dates and status as shown in Table below.

| ID | ChapterNumber | QueryID | QueryDate (DD-MM-YYY) | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Chapter-3 | Q-3-40 | 03-04-2021 | Forward |
| 2 | Chapter-3 | Q-3-40 | 05-04-2021 | Open |
| 3 | Chapter-3 | Q-3-40 | 07-04-2021 | Closed |
| 4 | Chapter-5 | Q-5-03 | 12-04-2021 | Open |
| 5 | Chapter-5 | Q-5-03 | 15-04-2021 | Closed |
| 6 | Chapter-5 | Q-5-04 | 16-04-2021 | Sent |

I want to show data table in ascending order in a DataGridView, with no repetition below the same question under ChapterNumber and  QueryID. I want entries in DataGridView like this;

| ID | ChapterNumber | QueryID | QueryDate (DD-MM-YYY) | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Chapter-3 | Q-3-40 | 07-04-2021 | Closed |
| 2 |  |  | 05-04-2021 | Open |
| 3 |  |  | 03-04-2021 | Forward |
| 4 | Chapter-5 | Q-5-03 | 15-04-2021 | Closed |
| 5 |  |  | 12-04-2021 | Open |
| 6 | Chapter-5 | Q-5-04 | 16-04-2021 | Sent |

My Code is like this;

```
Dim duplicates = From cust In SARDataSet.Table1
                         Order By cust.Query_ID Ascending


        DataGridView3.DataSource = duplicates
```

Please Guide me. I am new in this area.

Answer (score 0):

After the datagridview is display, add the following.

```
Private Sub Sort()
If dgv1.RowCount >= 2 Then
    For i = DataGridView3.RowCount - 1 To 1 Step -1
        If DataGridView3.Item(2, i).Value = DataGridView3.Item(2, i - 1).Value Then
            DataGridView3.Item(1, i).Value = ""
            DataGridView3.Item(2, i).Value = ""
        End If
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Mr. Yat Fei Leong, Actually, I want to take entries directly from datatable and show in datagridview.

Comment: I'm not sure you can create the exact format to the data table directly from linq but you certainly can perform the additional formatting after the data table has been generated before passing the result to dgv.